# Проблема с импортом файла в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Возникла ситуация, что в вузе задали реализовать программу с использованием определенных заголовочных файлов, импортировал их в проект но при подключении в программу возникла проблема, что VS их не видит, притом что между собой они видят друг друга(один заголовок импортируется в другой)

PS: На код в main не смотрите просто экспериментировал
[image: ][1]]

Comment: [Возможный ответ](https://coderoad.ru/3375380/C-Visual-Studios-не-удается-открыть-файл-include-eh#3375404)

Comment: Неужели нигде не учат, как подключать заголовочные файлы и библиотеки? "импортировал их в проект" - такого в VS вроде отродясь не было

Comment: а вот не учат, как это не удивительно. Я в свое время долго искал и методом проб и ошибок учился.

Comment: Работе с IDE мало где учат, и я ошибочно считал что просто добавляя существующий файл в свой проект, VS скопирует ее в проект, но как оказалось нет, так что да, часто приходится методом проб и ошибок искать ответы на свои вопросы

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы добавить уже созданный файл в свой проект в VS необходимо

1. Перенести нужный файл в свой проект в VS
2. Нажать ПКМ на "Исходные файлы" в обозревателе решений, далее "добавить", "существующий элемент"
3. Находим нужный файл в своем проекте и добавляем его